# Can I use wpdb to insert query results into a post?

Tags: wpdb

My website currently consists of content drawn from database queries, displayed with php. Specifically, there are 4 modules, each of which queries a different database to get all records that match the current date and display them in order. Is there a way to use wpdb to do similar queries and pull them into individual posts? The result I'm looking for is something similar to my current configuration: a WordPress site with only 4 posts, but the content within the posts changes depending on the date.

Answer (score 1):

`$wpdb` is a relatively simple wrapper around PHP's `mysql` functions. If you can do it with PHP/SQL then you can do it with `$wpdb`.

You're question is not detailed or specific enough to afford a more detailed answer though. Nor is it detailed enough to say whether `$wpdb` is the best, or even an acceptable` way to do what you are trying to do.

Edit the question and I will edit the answer.